# SolrJ Query about "AND" "OR"

Tags: solr, solrj

I have to query multiple fileds against an index(just like (id, name1, name2, name3)) using SolrJ, the relationship among these values are (id AND (name1 OR name2 OR name3)) .What should I do?

As Solrj api is rough documented, I expect someone could help me.

Regards

Answer (score 2):

First of all SolrJ documented pretty well. Take a look here - https://wiki.apache.org/solr/Solrj or here - http://www.solrtutorial.com/solrj-tutorial.html

Regading to your question:

```
    SolrQuery query = new SolrQuery();
    query.setQuery("id:12313 AND (name1:foo OR name2:bar OR name3:baz)");
    QueryResponse response = solr.query(query);
    SolrDocumentList results = response.getResults();
    for (int i = 0; i < results.size(); ++i) {
      System.out.println(results.get(i));
    }
```